# Math mode in LyX (on a Mac) does not display properly

Tags: fonts, math-mode, lyx, mac

When editing math mode basic symbols (such as `\in`, `\cdot`, `\leq`) do not render properly. Once I leave the edit mode of a particular equation it renders properly in the `cmr` font. (See screen shots below.)

I suspect it has to do with installing some font that Lyx uses while editing a formula.

I have a MacTex installation, Lyx 2.0.7.1, screen font: Times New Roman, OS 10.9.2.  Help appreciated.

Here is why I get: 
While editing math mode:
[image: text is wierd while editing]

After exiting editing math mode: 
[image: text appears after editing]

Comment: Seems like a bug in LyX. You might consider using LyX 2.1, which will be released in one day. If that doesn't work, file a bug report at http://www.lyx.org/trac

Comment: @scottkosty Indeed, LyX 2.1 solves the problem!

Comment: That's good news. Thanks for reporting back.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about a bug in LyX that is fixed in the latest version.

Answer (score 1):

This bug appears to have been fixed in LyX 2.1